# Can't download xlock into Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: package-management, 18.04

I have been trying to install xlock using the command

```
sudo apt-get install xlock
```

It outputs this instead of installing xlock:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package xlock is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'xlock' has no installation candidate
```

I have already done the two following commands before trying to install xlock respectively:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

In case the reader simply doesn't think xlock doesn't exist, here is the url for its man page: [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xlock)

I am new to Linux (six month year old user) so I am far from knowledgeable. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by `xlock`? Is it [PAM-related](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=xlock&mode=exactfilename&suite=bionic&arch=any)?

Comment: I’m not sure. I’m sorry. I’m new to Linux and I don’t know if it is. You could check the man page on the link if that helps though.

Answer (score 1):

You chose wrong package: `xclock` is available in `x11-apps` package.
Check on the [https://packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=xclock).

So the correct command is:

```
sudo apt-get install x11-apps
```

Also if you do not know/remember package name you can write its executable name in terminal to get the suggestion from `command-not-found` tool:

```
$ xlock

Command 'xlock' not found, did you mean:

  command 'lxlock' from deb lxlock
  command 'slock' from deb suckless-tools
  command 'vlock' from deb vlock
  command 'flock' from deb util-linux
  command 'rlock' from deb ruby-lockfile
  command 'wlock' from deb sendfile
  command 'xclock' from deb x11-apps
  command 'mlock' from deb mlock

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>

$ xclock 

Command 'xclock' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install x11-apps
```

---

If you really mean `xlock`, then according to its Ubuntu [`man xlock`-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=xlock) it is removed after Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

I found [PPA ppa:chaocrator-ppa/anarchy](https://launchpad.net/~chaocrator-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/anarchy) (it has package for 16.04 LTS, but not for 18.04 LTS) with needed `xlockmore-gl` package. You can install it with commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/chaocrator-ppa/anarchy/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xlockmore/xlockmore-gl_5.31-0~xenial_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./xlockmore-gl_5.31-0~xenial_amd64.deb
```

Comment: WOAH! I didn’t know that! I’ll check it out when I get home. I’m still out but thanks for sharing that information with me!

Comment: I tried installing and using all the commands printed when I type xlock into the CLI but it isn’t the command I’m looking for. I’m looking for the one described in the url in my question.

Comment: See updates. I found man-page and PPA with `xlock`.

Answer (score 1):

You can download and install it manually:

```
1. Download archive from http://sillycycle.com/xlock/
2. Unpack (into e.g. /tmp/xlockmore)
3. Install build deps: apt install build-essential libx11-dev libxext-dev libxt-dev
4. cd /tmp/xlockmore; ./configure; make; make install
```